# in passing another class object as argument, how can i add more objects

Tags: python-3.x

In below code i want to add 2 cars in list. how can i add?.here in should pass the the another class object as argument. When i want to add 2 or more model means how can i do?

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self,make,model,):
       self.make=make
       self.model=model
   def __repr__(self):
    return f'<Car {self.make} {self.model}>'
class Garage:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cars=[]
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.cars)
   def addcars(self,car):    
       if  not isinstance(car,Car):
           raise TypeError('you should pass only instance of the class car')
       self.cars.append(car)

g=Garage()
car=Car('ford','fogo') 
print(g.addcars(car))   
print(len(g))
```

Comment: You add them as in `g.addcars(Car('abc', 'def'))`? I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep using `g.addcars(Car('makename','modelname'))`:

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self,make,model,):
       self.make=make
       self.model=model
   def __repr__(self):
    return f'<Car {self.make} {self.model}>'
class Garage:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cars=[]
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.cars)
   def addCar(self,car):    
       if  not isinstance(car,Car):
           raise TypeError('you should pass only instance of the class car')
       self.cars.append(car)

g=Garage()
car=Car('ford','fogo') 
g.addCar(car)   
print(g)
g.addCar(Car('toyota','camry'))
print(g)
print(len(g))
```

If you want the ability to add a sequence of cars, make a new method that expects a sequence and calls `addcars` for each element in the sequence:

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self,make,model,):
       self.make=make
       self.model=model
   def __repr__(self):
    return f'<Car {self.make} {self.model}>'
class Garage:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cars=[]
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.cars)
   def addCar(self,car):    
       if  not isinstance(car,Car):
           raise TypeError('you should pass only instance of the class car')
       self.cars.append(car)

   def addMultipleCars(self,carSequence):
       for car in carSequence:
           self.addCar(car)

g=Garage()
car1=Car('ford','fogo')
car2=Car('toyota','camry') 
g.addMultipleCars((car1,car2))   
print(g)
```

(I renamed your method above to `addCar` because it's only adding one car)

Comment: @Madhumathi Glad I could help. Consider upvoting my answer and/or marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the grey checkmark (✔) over there <--. It gives me some reputation points and helps future visitors see from the search results that a working answer was found. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.